# image rendering problem

Tags: asp.net

i am unable to display any image bigger than 1mb in internet explorer, only the cross is displayed.
while in all other browsers image is displayed proper.
please suggest me the reason behind this and how to overcome with this issue...

Comment: Next to each answer to your questions, you'll see a hollow check.  For [each of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/357261/novicetodotnet), click the check next to the best / most helpful answer.

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?

Comment: it is unable to render any hi resolution image...

Answer (score 0):

That would happen if the image is corrupt or if there is a problem with your web server.

Try using different images.

Comment: no it doesn't work, i tried different image as well but of no avail.
all other browser render it proper..but internet explorer not rendering it

Comment: hello help me with this problem, i am  in big trouble and i am on edge to submit my project